# What is the equivalent function in AmiBroker AFL for "ta.change" in TradingView Pine-Script?

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, pine-script, trading, amibroker

I need to know the function from AmiBroker AFL which serves the same purpose as "ta.change" from TradingView Pine Script. "ta.change" Compares the current `source` value to its value `length` bars ago and returns the difference between the values when they are numerical. When a 'bool' source is used, returns `true` when the current source is different from the previous source.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AFL you can use Ref function to calculate change:

```
length = 5;
change = source - Ref( source, -length );
```